# RailsTutorial.org Learning Rails 5.3.4 Layout link tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

While following the tutorial 5.3.4 Layout Link Tests failed.

This is the test ran:

`$ rails generate integration_test site_layout`

This is the error received:

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
>
> /home/ubuntu/workspace/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run rake db:migrate to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.

Started

```
FAIL["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 2015-05-10 20:31:00 +0000]
test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1431289860.34s)
    Expected exactly 2 elements matching "a[href="/"]", found 0..
    Expected: 2
      Actual: 0
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>

1/1: [====================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.53147s
1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

This is the file (test/integration/site_layout_test.rb) changed prior to running the test and receiving the error:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    # test "the truth" do
    #   assert true
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code for the app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb file:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The test code looks good. The second part of the error message is about the test results (from "FAIL"). It expects 2 links to root_path, and it did find 0.
(test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:8 means: in line nr 8 of the file, which is about root_path.)
So the problem is not in your test file, but somewhere else.  
Have a look at your app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb -file. There are  2 root routes in there, and they are the count=2 from your test.

Comment: Thank you @Mauddev. I've been having issues with those from the beginning, they aren't working. The code for file app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb is below.

Comment: <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

Comment: Thank you again @Mauddev. I added the code to the _header.html.erb code to the body of the original submission. I tried using the help article you shared and couldn't get the formatting to work properly. I'll work on that for future submissions. Will you help me by looking in the original body at the end please?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mauddev. I found the error. There were two issues: 1 I was missing an '=' in the application.html.erb file and 2 there header code wasn't removed from the application.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was when I was writing root_path in `_header` partial instead of `#`, I didn't delete the `''`. After removing those everything worked just fine. Don't forget about `_footer` partial as well.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to raise your content quality up